# There is a relationship between the norm of a linear operator T and the values it takes on a space base?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on a infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ and let $B$ be an bases of $H$

Is there a relationship between the norm of $T$ and values in $T(B)$?

Comment: Do you mean an orthonormal basis? I don't understand exactly what you're saying

Comment: no... i know only that $B$ is a bases

Comment: do you mean basis? what is "bases" or "space base" supposed to mean?

Comment: Obviously there's a relationship, for example if $||T||=c$ then $||Tb||\le c||b||$ for all $b\in B$. That's too trivial to be interesting. Is there an inequality in the other direction? I don't think so...

Comment: exuse me ... i mean basis

Comment: David C. Ullrich.. but... $||Tb||=||T||*||b||$ or am i wrong?

Comment: i would have known if i can calulate $||T||$ just from $||Tb||$ for all b in B

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. There's no reason why $||Tb||$ should equal $||T||\,||b||$. See the answer I'm about to post...

Comment: David C. Ullrich... yes... i'm confused.. you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question's been somewhat clarified in a comment; as one would suspect, we want to know whether we can calculate $||T||$ from $||Tb||$ for $b\in B$. The answer is no.

Say $(e_1,e_2,\dots)$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$. Fix a positive integer $N$. Define $T$ by $$Te_n=\begin{cases}
e_1,&(1\le n\le N),
\\0,&(n>N).
\end{cases}$$Then $$||Te_n||\le||e_n||$$for every $n$. But if you let $$x=e_1+\dots+e_N$$then $$||Tx||=N^{1/2}||x||,$$so $$||T||\ge N^{1/2}.$$

Comment: David C. Ullrich... ok... it was just i want to know and you answered. thanks. nice proof